# svelte two components to access same object

Tags: svelte, openlayers-6, svelte-component, svelte-store

In my app, I have a route `map.svelte`

This has two child components: `Map.svelte` and `LayerSelector.svelte`

`Map.svelte` creates an OpenLayers `map` instance. `LayerSelector.svelte` needs to access this instance.

I am declaring the `map` instance in `map.svelte` and binding it to the two components, but do not appear to be able to access it in `LayerSelector.svelte`

map.svelte:

```
<script>
  import Map from '../components/Map.svelte';
  import MapLayerSelectorDialog from '../components/LayerSelector.svelte';
  let map;
</script>

<div class="map" id="map">
 <Map organisation={organisation} meta={meta} 
  showBackControl="true" showEditControl="true" showSearchControl="true"
  bind:map={map}
  on:mapready={initLayerSelector(map)}
  on:map-back={back=goBack}
  on:featureselected={featureSelected}
  on:togglelayerselector={toggleLayerSelector}
  on:togglemapsearch={toggleMapSearch}
  on:togglemapeditcontrol={toggleMapEdit}
 />
</div>

<MapLayerSelectorDialog bind:showDialog={showLayerSelectorDialog}
  bind:meta = {meta}
  bind:map={map}>
</MapLayerSelectorDialog>
```

Map.svelte:

```
export let map = null;
...
onMount(async () => {
  map = await initMap ('map', organisation, meta, startCoords);
});
...
```

initMap.js

```
export async function initMap (div, organisation, meta, startCoords) {
  var map = new Map({
    target: div, //'map',
    view: new View({
      center: fromLonLat ([1330601.87, 7916443.12]),
      zoom: 12,
    }),
  });
  addLayers (map, meta);
});
```

LayerSelector.svelte:

```
<script>
export let map
</script>
{#each map.getLayers() as layer}
  <p>{layer.get('name')}</p>
{/each}
```

Where might I be going wrong? Do I need to put the OpenLayers `map` instance in a writeable store mayebe?

Comment: To share a variable between several components you need to put it in the store : https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per se, your code should work. You can have two-way bindings of the variable to two separate child components like you are doing and then have one of them initialize it.

I created a [REPL that illustrates that it's possible](https://svelte.dev/repl/22d45b2472714f7193456aa03bc07526?version=3.43.1).

When you say you are not able to access the variable, what do you mean? You get an unexpected value or an error?

I suspect that the problem you have is that `map` will be `undefined` for a brief period before `onMount` runs. And `LayerSelector` will throw an error if `map` is not set.

If that is the issue, replacing `map.getLayers()` with e.g. `map ? map.getLayers() : []` will fix it.

That said, having a lot of two-way bindings makes for unclear data flow. I'd consider initializing the variable in `map.svelte` and then simply passing it to the other components to simplify the data flow a bit.